# Android Alarm manager to run a task on a specific time

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have read many articles, but non seems to work for me!

I have to schedule a repeating task with AlarmManager for everyday at 7:15.  The following method is set in an activity and registered a broadcast receiver for it!

```
private void setTask(Context context) {

    Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    updateTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    updateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7);
    updateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotifyUpdate.class);
    PendingIntent fireAlarm = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarms.setRepeating(alarms.RTC_WAKEUP, updateTime.getTimeInMillis(), alarms.INTERVAL_DAY, fireAlarm);
}
```

The problem is when I run the app the method gets executed immediately regardless of the time set, but not executing at (7:15).

Any Idea?

Comment: Is the class `NotifyUpdate` a `Service` or a `BroadcastReceiver`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It is a BroadcastReceiver

Comment: The alarm seems to be fine. The deviation can be somewhere else ... are you sure you don't call the method from the BroadcastReceiver somewhere else manually? Furthermore the Android6+ Doze Mode can interfere with AlarmManager if you did not add your app to the optimization exception list.

Comment: With `setRepeating` you need to make sure that the time has not already been reached today, otherwise (according to docs) `If the stated trigger time is in the past, the alarm will be triggered immediately, with an alarm count depending on how far in the past the trigger time is relative to the repeat interval.`

Comment: The method is called only from the MainActivity on which it is created! I am setting different times but still no luck. I am checking the app in KitKat 4.4.2

Answer (score 0):

Try this before setting alarm

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
if (updateTime.before(now)) {
            updateTime.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);  // if its in the past increment
}

alarms.setRepeating(alarms.RTC_WAKEUP, updateTime.getTimeInMillis(), alarms.INTERVAL_DAY, fireAlarm);
```

You said that you have immediate triggering not depending on time. It's happening because updateTime-object references at time in the past, so the goal is to set an alarm to 7:15 in the future. This will help to avoid immediate triggering.

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: In my code I have taken the calendar instance and saved on the updateTime! Shall I get another instance and save it on the now?!!